# MySQL Rollup - All possible column super aggregations

Tags: mysql

I have this query which uses a rollup.

```
Select
    ItemTypeId,
    unitid,
    DealerId,
    DistrictId,
    t1.UserId,
    sum(StockUnits) as StockUnits,
    sum(StockQuantity) as StockQuantity
from datatable
group by ItemTypeId asc,UnitId asc,DealerId asc,DistrictId asc , UserId asc
with rollup
```

However, I am unable to obtain all of the super aggregations.

In this case, I am unable to get the following combinations

(ItemTypeId,UnitId,UserId,DistrictId)
,(ItemTypeId,UnitId,UserId,DistrictId,DealerId)

The reason being a userid can be available for multiple districts. Also, a userid can be available for multiple districts and dealers

In the image below the first few rows are the aggregations that groupbyrollup builds

The rows in blue is not what I am able to generate

http://i66.tinypic.com/2csaus9.png

Any idea on how I can get these super aggregations?

Thanks in advance
Rathi

Comment: can you post example dataset and desired output?
what is "super-aggregations"?

Comment: Hi Yossi - I have edited the main post to include an example